# Is it valid to call Stored procedure after WHEN in snowflake TASK

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to call stored procedure while creating snowflake tasks after **WHEN**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK SCHEMA.TASK1
  warehouse = '..'
  schedule = '5 minute'
WHEN
    CALL DB.SCHEMA.CHECK_STATUS('arg1');
as
CALL DB.SCHEMA.ETL('arg1');
```

Is this valid,

```
WHEN
    CALL DB.SCHEMA.CHECK_STATUS('arg1');
```

if yes how do we achieve this to return **true** or **false** in task.
Snowflake documentation link - https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-task.html#examples

I am getting following error

> SQL compilation error: syntax error line 5 at position 9 unexpected
> 'DB'.

Comment: I would look into consolidating the CHECK_STATUS and and ETL stored procedures into a single SP. If the CHECK_STATUS condition is not met, exit the SP. If it is met, continue with the ETL portion. Although you could use SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA to avoid running ETL, just running the CHECK_STATUS is going to require a running warehouse. In other words, it's not going to save anything by separating the check and the ETL action.

Answer (score 0):

Given the [CREATE TASK](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-task.html) documentation.

Currently, only the [SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_stream_has_data.html) function is supported for evaluation in the WHEN parameter.

Comment: Do you know any alternatives ? to achieve above scenario ?

Comment: You can create a stored procedure that will check your condition : if condition is met it will launch the next queries. You can then call this procedure in your TASK : if condition is not met then it will stop there.